# pyqt setting colour to QMenuBar

Tags: pyqt

I'm trying to change the colour to my menubar but it doesn't seem to be working.  Not sure what I did wrong.

```py
self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar()
self.menuBar.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on OSX, this will have no effect as it uses the systems menu.

For other platforms, you might need to be setting it on the item subcontrol:

```py
self.menuBar.setStyleSheet("QMenuBar::item { color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }")
```